# How to solve this Python import circular reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, circular-reference

I have a class JCheq, with a static var named 'logger'.

JCheq imports module `printing_systems`, but I need to use `JCheq.logger` from `printing_systems`.

My code does not compile after I put `import JCheq` in `printing_systems.py`.

jcheq.py

```
from printing_systems import printing_systems
from logger import logger

class JCheq:
    logger = logger.Logger('logs/jcheq.log', loglevel=logger.Logger.INFO)

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    ...
```

printing_systems/printing_systems.py

```
from jcheq import JCheq
class WinLPR:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def send(spool, params):
        temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        try:
            JCheq.logger.log('Creando archivo temporal en dir: ' + temp_dir, logger.Logger.TRACE)
```

Error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jsivil/Desktop/Proyectos/UNPAZ/jcheq/jcheq/jcheq.py", line 12, in <module>
    from printing_systems import printing_systems
  File "/home/jsivil/Desktop/Proyectos/UNPAZ/jcheq/jcheq/printing_systems/printing_systems.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jcheq import JCheq
  File "/home/jsivil/Desktop/Proyectos/UNPAZ/jcheq/jcheq/jcheq.py", line 12, in <module>
    from printing_systems import printing_systems
ImportError: cannot import name 'printing_systems'
```

Comment: Don't make the references circular anymore (decompose `printing_systems`, e.g.).  Or you can "cheat" and move the import out of global scope to where it's used.

Comment: um... is there a variable called `printing_systems` in the `printing_systems` module? You are trying to import a variable from the module instead of just `import printing_systems`

Comment: @BrianCain Yes I moved the import to the methods and now it works, but I don't know if that is acceptable... what do you mean with decomposing?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen printing_systems.py is inside printing_systems directory. I did not find a way to make it simpler.

Comment: which means you are trying to import from a package and need a `__init__.py` for python to recognize it as a package

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen jcheq.py is in 'root', then there are subdirectories, like printing_systems.

Comment: yes sorry, realized I could get that information from looking at the traceback, you do have an `__init__.py` though right?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, yes, all was working, except now that I need to use JCheq.logger from printing_systems.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107150/discussion-between-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen-and-jorgeefg).

Comment: @JorgeeFG I would like to continue this in chat because I don't think you have provided a MCVE, I was able to run your example without problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the import statement in the function is commonly used to solve circular imports. It is handy in cases when restructuring your application would be too costly (if useful at all).

Another solution would be to move `JCheq.logger` into its own module that both `jcheq.py` and `printing_systems/printing_systems.py` would import.

Or, you could make logger.Logger a factory function backed by some registry (or simply memoize it) so that it returns the same logger when the same arguments are given. This way, `printing_system.py` would simple import `logger` instead of importing `jcheq`.

Comment: Well, I opted for the factory approach, seems to work. One problem I found with it is that since import printing_systems is on top of JCheq, I have to first import LoggerFactory and then having logger be a global var right after it, then import printing_systems. Else printing_systems will be parsed first and a logger with the same path but different log_level will be created (since log_level should be only set once and it is an optional argument)

Comment: Have you tried memoizing `logger.Logger` ? SInce you are using Python 3, you can quickly do this using `functools.lru_cache`. I think it would solve the import order issue.